# MMC AsyncStatus (inside MmcListView) is not displaying status

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mmc, mmc3

When using the MMC (Microsoft Management Console) 3.0 I cannot get AsyncStatus message shown in console window.

I assume it is supposed to be **displayed in the status bar of the MMC**.

When using the StandardVerb (like `OnRefresh` or `OnExpand`) at least it is working with its default message (like `Expand: In  progress...`)

However, when I try to use `status.ReportProgress([...])` or `status.Complete([...])` it does not work.

Example:

```
class MyMMCListview : MmcListView {
    [...]
    protected override void OnAction(Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Action action, AsyncStatus status)
    {
        status.ReportProgress(1, 2, "Loading 1");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        status.ReportProgress(2, 2, "Loading 2");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        // default behavior
        base.OnAction(action, status)

        // Nothing done successfully
        status.Complete("Done", true);
    }
    [...]
}
```

MmcListView: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.managementconsole.mmclistview_members(v=vs.90).aspx

AsyncStatus: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.managementconsole.asyncstatus(v=vs.85).aspx

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? i have the same problem :(

Comment: @zaitsman I did not actually. I solved it that way to display status messages through the nodes or listview

Comment: have you got an example maybe, especially with listview? Did you mean you write a custom winforms control that hosts listview or..? And with nodes -> I guess I still want the mmclistview control, just handover the status to scopenode somehow to update the status bar...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this several times and it seems that `ReportProgress` and `Complete` are showing a message in the status bar only when they where called from an override in a `ScopeNode`.